# keyStore.getKey(alias, password) returns NULL

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, jks

I need sign some string message, but `keyStore.getKey()` returns null.
What I did:
I imported certificate:

```
keytool -importcert -file cert.cer -keystore cert.jks -alias "cert"
```

My java code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(this.keystoretype);
File keyStoreFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:kkb/"+keystoreFileName);
FileInputStream keyStoreFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile.getPath());
keyStore.load(keyStoreFileInputStream, storePassArray);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(this.signalgorythm);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, keypassArray);
```

`getKey()` returns null because this line code in the JavaKeyStore class, engineGetKey method:

```
public Key engineGetKey(String alias, char[] password)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException
{
    Object entry = entries.get(convertAlias(alias));
    if (entry == null || !(entry instanceof KeyEntry)) {
        return null;
}
```

Condition "instanceof" return false, because "entry" object of class "JavaKeyStore$TrustedCertEntry".
What I do wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

> I imported certificate:
>   
>   keytool -importcert -file cert.cer -keystore cert.jks -alias "cert"

Indeed, you have imported **a certificate containing a public key**.

> Condition "instanceof" return false, because "entry" object of class "JavaKeyStore$TrustedCertEntry". 
>   What I do wrong?

And now you call:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, keypassArray);
```

There is no **private key**, only a certificate (usually the X509Certificate), which contains a public key.

> Can you help me?

It depends what do you want / need.

If you need a private key (or a keypair), e.g. for signing, you will need to import the whole keypair (e.g. from different keystore).

If a certificate or public key is enough (e.g. for signature validation), you may get the certificate or its public key

```
keystore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey()
```

Edit:

> I have this files: ca.cer, cert.cer, cert.der, cert.jks, cert.p12, cert.pfx, cert.pk8, cert.prv, cert.pub, kkbca_test.der, kkbca_test.pub. Which of them I need import too?

Usually PFX or P12 files contain the private key (both are pkcs12 keystores).

To import a private key from pkcs12 keystore, just search the internetm example: https://jackstromberg.com/2013/05/importing-a-ssl-certificate-into-a-java-keystore-via-a-pkcs12-file/

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore whateverthefileis.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore mykeystore -destalias aliasname -deststoretype JKS
```

If you are more comfortable with UI tools, you can use the *keystore-explorer* application to manage/import keys and certificates.

Comment: I have this files:  
ca.cer,  
cert.cer,   
cert.der,
cert.jks,
cert.p12,
cert.pfx,
cert.pk8,
cert.prv,
cert.pub,
kkbca_test.der,
kkbca_test.pub.
Which of them I need import too?

Comment: @Bekarys updated the answer for importing a keypair

Comment: thank you for you attention, i solved it by change jks file by other. It's doesn't need to import, just sign some string.